# Alinhamento central aparece corretamente no preview da activity, mas não na execução do app?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

Coloquei alinhamento ao centro para todas os textView e na preview da activity, ainda no android studio, tudo certo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém quando executo o app o mesmo não acontece:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mesmo tendo setado o layout_width dos textViews como math_parent para os mesmos oculparem toda a extensão do aparelho na horinzontal, não obtivesse o resultado esperado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

xlm da activity:

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:customfontdemo="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="genesysgeneration.font2.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="fonte padraum" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginTop="159dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="********** asdasd **********" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="118dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView\nasdlaslkdj\nasodjaosdjoa" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Para que eles fiquem alinhados voce precisa usar gravity: coloca isso no seu textview `android:gravity="center"` que vai centralizar

Comment: Cadê seu código?

Comment: Com as instruções de @ArmandoMarquesSobrinho consegui resolver Ack Lay, de qq forma colocarei o código

Comment: opa! isso mesmo amigo Boneco Sinforoso, mas eu positivei a resposta do @Thiago Leon porque ela está corretissima.

Comment: existe alguma diferença entre gravity center e center_horizontal?

Comment: Boneco sinforoso
o center_horizontal coloca o conteudo no meio da tela porem na sua posição na altura

ja o center ele deixa o conteudo centralizado no meio da tela e no meio da altura tambem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize o Seguinte codigo nas suas textviews

`android:gravity = "center"` para centralizar horizontalmente e verticalmente na sua função,caso queira uma centralização especifica como horizontal  ficaria `android:gravity="center_horizontal"`

caso queira mais informações sobre o assunto
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Gravity.html